# Packaging an exe to have one file, similar to on mac with .app

Tags: resources, packaging, exe

I am trying to create a standalone app with a resources folder that is writable.  I would like to include this in the exe, similar as to how it is done on OSX with an .app.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In OS X, an `.app` isn't just a file, it's actually a directory with a whole directory tree underneath it. The Finder knows this and doesn't show the files inside an `.app` directory.

Comment: Yes. Is there anyway of doing this in an exe? Basically, it's to keep the resources directory relatively private, however the app needs to write there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're talking about a modern Windows OS you're probably going to have problems with this even if you could come up with a solution. Most apps gets put under the Program Files directory and by default only Admins have write permissions there so it's generally seen as a bad thing to store anything the app needs to write to next to the executable in Windows.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is it's a standalone app that runs from a USB key. It downloads resources (text + images) from the internet and stores them locally. The client would like that these are semi-protected

Comment: @davidinbcn: Maybe you could just encrypt the resources with some resource-light (since it sounds like it just have to look secure) encryption.